# Sockets php java

Tags: java, php, sockets

I'm having problems with sockets, in fact I'm trying to send a socket from a php script to a java server:

Here is my php:

```
<form action="#" method="Post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Message" name="msg">
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['msg'])) {
    $address="127.0.0.1";
    $port="43278";
    $msg = $_POST['msg'];

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

    socket_sendto($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $address, $port);

    echo "<p>Message sent</p>";
}
```

And here is my java server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(43278);

    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Socket received");

    serverSocket.close();
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

The java server does'nt receive anything, so I tried to send a socket via a java program and it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket socket;
    socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 43278);
    socket.close();
}
```

But I'm not sure if the problem is due to the php script because this software seems to receive the socket from php:

[image]

Finaly I think it's due to the ip address but I could'nt find informations about it so I'm not sure...

Regards.

Comment: the result from `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` ?

Comment: It's my local IP: Pc-Florian/192.168.56.1, but if I replace it by "127.0.0.1" the server still gets the socket

Comment: try to debug your script `if($socket) { $send = socket_sendto($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $address, $port); if($send !== -1) { print 'send!'; } else { print 'fail!' } } else { print 'connection failed!'; }`

Comment: and try to set $address in to double quote mark -> `"$address"`

Comment: Well, apparently the socket is sent but I think it has to do with the java program but I don't get why

Comment: Where do I put $adress in double quote ? I tried here socket_sendto($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, "$address", $port); but it does'nt do nothing

Comment: ok, remove quote marks. it's only for test.

Comment: ok, it's done, I'm trying to check the java program

Comment: look here for java server example https://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/socket.html

Comment: Ho nice! it worked, I used the UDPServer.java example. In fact I had to use a DatagramSocket instead of the ServerSocket. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

it worked, I used the UDPServer.java example. In fact I had to use a DatagramSocket instead of the ServerSocket. – Florian Merle